# How can I use gettext in jupyter-notebook/python interactive mode?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, gettext

I use the following code, which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434578/convert-translated-country-names-to-alpha2-with-pycountry-and-gettext), to get country codes from their russian names.

```
def get_country_code(russian_name):
    gettext.translation('iso3166', pycountry.LOCALES_DIR, languages=['RU']).install()
    country_code = ''.join([country.alpha_2 for country in pycountry.countries if _(country.name) == russian_name])
    return country_code
```

But as I try to use this function in my jupyter-notebook, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Is seems like this is because in jupyter as well as in interactive mode _ means the result of the previous calculation, but gettext define it as its function.

How can I execute this code in Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to the problem. The install() function sets variable _ in builtins like this:

```
builtins.__dict__['_'] = self.gettext
```

So we can use this function instead.

```
def get_country_code(russian_name):
    rus = gettext.translation('iso3166', pycountry.LOCALES_DIR, languages=['RU'])
    rus.install()
    country_code = ''.join([country.alpha_2 for country in pycountry.countries if rus.gettext(country.name) == russian_name]) # u'FR'
    return country_code
```